# XOR of all the elements of form (start + 2 * i) where i ranges from 0 to n - 1

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit, bit-shift, xor, bitwise-xor

**Background:**

This question is actually on leetcode categorized as an easy problem with a solution of having time complexity of O(N).

But I am having hard time understanding solutions by other users of time complexity of O(1) using bit manipulation and some observations.

**Problem statement:**

Given an integer `n` and an integer `start`.

Define an array `nums` where `nums[i] = start + 2*i` (0-indexed) and `n == nums.length`.

Return the bitwise XOR of all elements of nums.

**O(1) solution by a user:**

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    int xorOperation(int n, int start) {
        int first = start & 1;
        start = start >> 1;
        if(start % 2 == 0){
            switch(n % 4){
                case 0: return 0;
                case 1: return ((start + n - 1) << 1) + first;
                case 2: return 2;
                case 3: return ((1 ^ (start + n - 1)) << 1) + first;
            } 
        } else {
            switch(n % 4){
                case 0: return (start ^ 1 ^ (start + n - 1)) << 1;
                case 1: return (start << 1) + first;
                case 2: return (start ^ (start + n - 1)) << 1;
                case 3: return ((start ^ 1) << 1) + first;
            } 
        }
        return 0; //unreachable
    }
};
```

He said that he used an observation that `x ^ (x + 1) = 1` when x is an even number but I cannot understand how this information is useful.

Some information regarding concept that I might not be aware will be very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why the code you posted is so complicated but I think I got a solution that is better explainable ( and simpler to boot )

---

First, let's take a few observations

1. you are always adding a 2 * number, so the lowest bit of *start* is just xor-ed n times with itself, which is the same as if it were and-ed with *n&1* ( if *n* is odd, it stays as it is, if it's even, it's always 0 ). So, let's calculate it separately and shunt it right to the output and deal just with the rest

   ```java
   int firstBit = start & n & 1;
   int startHi = start >> 1;
   // the formula now being just num[i]=startHi+i
   // ... here be computation ...
   //
   return firstBit | ( resultHi << 1 );
   ```
2. xor is associative and its own inverse, so

   `A^B^C^D^E^F^G^H = (A^B^C^D)^(E^F^G^H)`

   `(E^F^G^H) = (A^B^C^D)^(A^B^C^D^E^F^G^H)`

   so we can solve the *xor(m...n)* in terms of *xor(0...m)* and *xor(0...n)* or, in terms of the *start* and *n*, we can

   `(start+0^start+1^...start+n-1) = (0^1^2^....start-1) ^ (0^1^2^....start+n-1)`

   let's thus define a simpler 1 param function *xor0(k)*, the result will thus be

   ```java
       int firstBit = start & n & 1;
       int startHi = start >> 1;
       int resultHi = xor0(startHi)^xor0(startHi+n);
       return firstBit | ( resultHi << 1 );
   ```
3. if we are xor-ing numbers 0...*k-1*, look what the bits look like

   - the first bit goes like `0101 0101 0101 0101 0101`,

     so the xor-ed value goes like `0110 0110 0110 0110`
     and we can see the pattern immediately and compute

     `int firstBit = (k&2)>>1;`
   - for all the other bits, take for example bit 2,

     it goes `0000 1111 0000 1111`

     so the xor-ed value is `0000 1010 0000 1010`

     or bit 3 `0000 0000 1111 1111 0000 0000 1111 1111`

     the xor-ed value being `0000 0000 1010 1010 0000 0000 1010 1010`,

   we can also see the pattern right away: if the bit is 0 it stays 0, if the bit is 1, the output alternates between 1 for odd *k* and 0 for even *k*, so we can just
   `int higherBits= (k-1) & ( (k&1)==0 ? 0 : -2 );`

and we thus have the final version ( in java, with self-check comparing it to the reference *O(N)* implementation )

```java
package xortest;

public class XorTest {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        for (int s = 0; s < 16; s++) {
            for (int n = 0; n < 16; n++) {
                int r = xorReference(s, n);
                int x = xorOperation(s, n);
                System.out.println(String.format("s=%02d n=%02d ref=%08x val=%08x%s", s, n, r, x, x == r ? "" : " ERROR"));
            }
        }
    }

    static int xor0(int k) {
        int firstBit = (k & 2) >> 1;
        int higherBits = (k - 1) & ((k & 1) == 0 ? 0 : -2);
        return higherBits | firstBit;
    }

    static int xorOperation(int start, int n) {
        int firstBit = start & n & 1;
        int startHi = start >> 1;
        int resultHi = xor0(startHi) ^ xor0(startHi + n);
        return firstBit | (resultHi << 1);
    }

    static int xorReference(int start, int n) {
        int xor = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            xor ^= start + 2 * i;
        }
        return xor;
    }
    
}
```